# MYSQL union and left join not returning any results

Tags: mysql

I have got unions getting out data from various tables, what I would like to do is left join a separate query (as below) and match on the email. Something isn't quite right as it doesn't return any results at all. Both queries work independently. I want everything from the unions on the left and whatever matches on the right.

Help appreciated..

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT email_address AS email, 
                title, 
                forename      AS first_name, 
                surname       AS last_name, 
                'wifi'        AS source, 
                postcode      AS postcode 
FROM   source1 
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT email, 
                title, 
                first_name, 
                last_name, 
                'chauntry' AS source, 
                post_code  AS postcode 
FROM   source2 
WHERE  mailing_indicator = 1) AS x 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT email, 
                 Avg(amount_paid)                AS avg_paid, 
                 Count(*)                        AS no_times_booked, 
                 Count(DISTINCT( Month(added) )) AS unique_months 
          FROM   chauntry 
          WHERE  added >= Now() - INTERVAL 1 year 
                 AND mailing_indicator = 1 
          GROUP  BY email) AS y 
          ON x.email = y.email
```

here is the rough data schema

```
Source 1

email          | title | first_name | last_name | source

test1@test.com |   Mr  | name       | surname   | source1
test2@test.com |   Mr  | name       | surname   | source1
test3@test.com |   Mr  | name       | surname   | source1
```

Union

Source 2

```
email          | title | first_name | last_name | source

test4@test.com |   Mr  |   name     | surname   | source2
test5@test.com |   Mr  |   name     | surname   | source2
test6@test.com |   Mr  |   name     | surname   | source2
```

Source 3 (Left join)

```
email           | amount_paid | booking_date
test1@test.com  | 50.00       | 2010-01-13
test1@test.com  | 50.00       | 2010-01-13
```

Looking for

```
email | title | first_name | last_name | source | avg_spend | number_bookings | unique_months

test1@test.com | Mr | name | surname | source1  | 50.00     |  2              | 1
test2@test.com | Mr | name | surname | source1
test3@test.com | Mr | name | surname | source1
test4@test.com | Mr | name | surname | source2
test5@test.com | Mr | name | surname | source2
test6@test.com | Mr | name | surname | source2
```

Comment: It would be easier to determine what might be wrong given sample data for tables.  Any chance you could give us a mock schema?

Comment: To keep it simple, just use 3 sources in the mockup